# Where can I find the IC06 74HC/HCT/HCU/HCMOS Logic Package Outlines

Tags: digital-logic

I am looking at using the [74HCT4514PW](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Nexperia/74HCT4514PW112?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtxONTBFIcRfsgCRr8SlzJ%2ftEwW3t97i94%3d)  I want to ensure the footprint I am using is correct (I have screwed up in the past using a 0.4mm "TSSOP" footprint when I should have used a 0.65mm "TSSOP" footprint)

The mouser product page links to [a datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/916/74HC_HCT4514_CNV-1319005.pdf) but unfortunately it does not contain details of the package outlines, instead it references "IC06 74HC/HCT/HCU/HCMOS Logic Package Outlines"

Where can I find this document, it does not appear to be obvious in a google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second page of google results I found a [question on the arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=16330.0) this had a link to http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/logic/

The link was dead, presumablly as a result of the NXP/Nexperia split, but the [internet archive has a copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20130722110127/http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/logic/)

There doesn't seem to be any document whose title precisely matches the referenced "IC06 74HC/HCT/HCU/HCMOS Logic Package Outlines" , however there seem to be a pair of documents containing the relavent information

[IC06 74HC/T High-Speed CMOS Package Information](http://web.archive.org/web/20121203003220/http://ics.nxp.com:80/support/documents/logic/pdf/family.hcmos.package.information.pdf) contains a mapping table showing which IC goes with which footprint.

[IC06 74HC/T Package Outline Drawings Package Information](http://web.archive.org/web/20121203004331/http://ics.nxp.com:80/support/documents/logic/pdf/family.hcmos.package.outlines.pdf) has the actual package drawings.

Answer (score 1):

The Mouser listing you link to specifies the package as "SOT-355".
Nexperia has a datasheet for their [SOT355-1 package](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/outline-drawing/SOT355-1.pdf) where it's described as having a 0.65mm pitch.
Make sure you check the package width of your footprint too.

Answer (score 1):

Philips Semiconductor division spun out to become NXP, and you can find these documents here on page 2 for old SOIC’s

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN2409.pdf

But they dropped the Philips package style number.  Look for

SOT355-1, TSSOP24, plastic, thin shrink small outline package; 24 leads; 0.65 mm pitch; 7.8 mm x 4.4 mm x 1.1 mm ...

https://componentsearchengine.com/common/footprintPreview.php?partID=908132

Philip’s Name SOT355-1.
Second Name TSSOP24.
JEDEC MO-153